# eclipse - folders for classes

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, namespaces, directory

I have a android app in eclipse, and by the time I have more and more classes in it.

[image]

As you can see, its pretty messy.

In visual studio I know how to add sub folders in the project, and organize the classes in a more ordered way (for example `Interfaces` folder, `Client` folder etc).

How can I do it in eclipse without messing with the namespaces or causing any errors? do I add packages?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create package inside of "com.example.tremp" by right-clicking it.

I think it should have a name including the parent package name (e.g. "com.example.tremp.activities"), but I have tried naming it without parent package name (e.g. "activities") and it worked fine by me.

Comment: thanks for your answer. and it shouldn't do anything to the namespaces\anything like that?

Comment: @OfekAgmon No, it should automatically do everything needed, so you shouldn't worry about it

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to create new packages and then assign each class to a package .